# Couldn't find Message with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I define @message in messages.rb at index action, the error jumps: Couldn't find Message with 'id'=   while go to /messages. But I also defined @message at destroy action and it never leads to this error.

app/controllers/messages.rb

```
  class MessagesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

def new
    @message = current_user.messages.build
end

def create
    @message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)
    if @message.save
        redirect_to messages_path
    else
        render '/messages/new'
    end
end

def edit
end

def update
end

def destroy
    @message = Message.find(params[:id])
    @message.destroy
    redirect_to '/messages'
end

def index
    @messages = Message.order(id: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page])
    @message = Message.find(params[:id])
end

protected

def setup
end

def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:content)
end
```

end

errors in logs:

> Started GET "/messages" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 15:57:59 +0800
>   Processing by MessagesController#index as HTML
>     User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
>     Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
>   Completed 404 Not Found in 20ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
>   ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Message with 'id'=):
>     app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:31:in `index'

I don't know why it happens, does it have any relationship with paginate? cause I find other instance variables can defined with *@var = Var.find(params[:id])* if no instance variables like *@vars = Var.paginate(page: params[:page])* defined in the same action.

Comment: You need to pass id, there is no id being passed. Best practice is index provide collections of records. But if it is your requirement, then u need to pass id.

Comment: thanks, and how can I pass id in index.html.erb?

Comment: http://yourwebsite/messages?id=1

Comment: Why you want to display all messages and get single message_id at same page?

Comment: @ChitrankSamaiya I jast want to specify each message an id like <div id="message-<%= message.id %>"> which may get by js.

Comment: @killernova explain behavior to sort out your problem.

Comment: @ChitrankSamaiya OK, actually I'm practicing the js in demo. For example, I want visitors click the message and change the color of the message by using toggleClass or  css .  `<script type=text/javascript>
$("#messages-content-<%= @message.id %>").click(function(){
 $(this).css("color", "green")
})
</script>
`

Comment: This is entirely seperate question, first of all mark an answer which people answered bcoz your primary question is answered. And for above script you dont need unique id, applying class can solve you problem. Please ask seperate question, this is irrelevent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove this line from your `index` action:

@message = Message.find(params[:id])

It doesn't work, because there isn't `id` parameter in `params`. In `destroy` action it present because it is passed via routes. For clarification, compare 2 pathes:

```
Get /messages
Delete /messages/2
```

In second route 2 represents id of a message. In first one it is absent.

**Update**

For your question in comment:

```
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
  <div id="message-<%= message.id %>">
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it makes me much more clear now.  I have another question: if I have a list of messages in /messages, and I want to specify an id to each message like `<div id="message-<%= @message.id %>">`, how should I write the code?

Comment: Yes, I've done this before. But I want use id in js like $("#message-<%= @message.id %>"), and this will lead to not defined variable error cause I didn't define in index.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to this line in your index action.

```
@message = Message.find(params[:id])
```

After destroy action `params[:id]` is no longer available. This line is not required. If you want to use it you have to specify the params.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I specify the params? I'm new on rails.